# Java Play get value of dropdownbox and put it in Form object

Tags: java, forms, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

When hitting the "Save simulation" button I need to know which "option" has been selected in the dropdown box. How to create a field using scala and put it in the testForm object?

```
@(testForm: Form[Test], areas: List[AreaDefinition]) 

@import helper._

@main("Test") {

@form(routes.TestController.newTest()) {

    <table border="0" id="areasensor_table">
        <tr id="areasensor_row0">
            <td>
                <div id="wrapperForArea">
                    <select id="selectedArea"> @for(area <- areas) {
                        <option value="@area.uniqueid">@area.name</option>}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<div class="pull-right">
<button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Save simulation</button>
</div>
    }
}
```

TestController:

```
    Form<Test> filledForm = Form.form(Test.class).bindFromRequest();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Name attribute in select needs to be specified so that you can retrieve it on server side

```
<select name="area"> @for(area <- areas) {
    <option value="@area.uniqueid">@area.name</option>}
</select>
```